# How to make git detect errors in config?

Tags: git, git-config

On one of my machines I made a typo when configuring git, which resulted in this entry in the .gitconfig file:

```
[credentials]
    helper = cache
```

Can you spot the error? I spelled credential**s** instead of credential. Of course, git accepted this without any error/warning/biting remark.

Is there a way to ask git to validate the config file and flag any entry that:

- is ignored (e.g. `alias pull = pull --no-ff`)
- does not match any available configuration variable (like the above `credentials` vs. `credential` mismatch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  The reason for this is that the configuration file format is *deliberately* free-form; any entries that Git doesn't use are ignored, so that *other programs* can create such entries.  For all Git knows, there's some non-Git program that uses `credentials.helper` for something.

(It would make some sense for Git to detect things that it does know about but skips, such as aliases for built-in commands.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I can accept the fact that the answer is no, but I am not entirely convinced by the rationale. After all, this is `.gitconfig` file, not `.otherprogramconfig` file.
Anyway, I would find something like `git config --validate` very useful, if it could flag potential problems (just output a message, not reject the file or remove offending entries). Especially since `git help --config` lists all available configuration variables, so such a utility can be implemented without huge effort. Am I missing something?

Comment: Git is a tool-set, not a solution. Git's authors expect Git users to write their own tools to add to the tool-set, and expect those users to add new configuration items. Git authors add their own configuration items sometimes, and some users like to pre-configure new items that aren't in their Git version yet, or use multiple Git versions. You may not agree with the Git authors here, but that's their general reasoning.

Comment: Note that Git config files are used by other programs that run `git config --file <path> --get ...` to read other files. The general idea of free-form config files is pretty common in other software as well. See also the Wikipedia article on [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

Comment: Note that you're not alone in this desire for some sort of syntax checking. Making something that's smart enough to detect common errors would probably do a great service! :-)

Comment: came looking for something similar.. consider leveraging https://www.schemastore.org/json/?